# Taxonomy terms display

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I want to display all taxonomy terms hiearchicaly exactly like it is displayed in the administration.

Here is the sccrenshot of the administration of the taxonomy and i want to display + the titles of the articles (not included in the screenshot)[image] the exact same thing to the users on the front-end of my drupal website.

Answer (score 1):

To build this structure there is quite some code necessary. You can see this in Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary::buildForm().

It might be easier to reuse the code that builds the admin page.

Load the admin form for the terms overview:

```
$vocabulary = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary::load('tags');
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\taxonomy\Form\OverviewTerms', $vocabulary);
```

Extract only the terms, as we don't need the rest of the form:

```
$terms = $form['terms'];
```

Then you can remove things you don't need, for example the operations:

```
  foreach ($terms as $key => &$term) {
    if (strpos($key, 'tid:') === 0) {
      if (isset($term['operations'])) {
        unset($term['operations']);
      }
    }
  }
  unset($term);
```

This will result in a table, where there is still the drag and drop javascript active. You can do more housekeeping, until you have the result you want.

The pager of this form should still work, so you can display the second page by appending "?page=1" to the url.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that i could maybe do that with Views but maybe Views isn't enough. I'm will give it a go :)